# Measure SQL Azure Transaction Rate

Tags: performance, azure-sql-database

We are on SQL Azure v12 Standard/S2 Service Tier and are not satisfied with the performance so I am trying to measure where the bottleneck is. I realize that we could be hitting the limits of the S2 service tier. S2 has 50 DTU and 2,570 transactions per minute limitation.

**Memory Pressure:**
I looked at the `sys.dm_exec_query_memory_grants` and there are no pending memory grants and the requested memory is being granted. 
Page Life expectancy is about 600.

**DTU**
The average DTU doesn't seem to be more than 50% unitized. avg_cpu_percent and avg_data_io_percent are rarely over 50%. avg_memory_usage_percent stays at 99%.
I got this information from the `sys.dm_db_resource_stats`

**Transactions Per Sec**
How do I measure Transactions/Sec in SQL Azure? The DMV `sys.dm_os_performance_counters` for Transactions/Sec doesn't have any values for the User databases. it has values for system databases.

Comment: with v12 you can try [Query Store](http://aka.ms/querystore). Is not going to give to TPM, but will give you execution times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this script written by Dimitri Furman from Microsoft. It will  measure transactions/sec per database.  You need to run this against the database where you want to measure transactions/sec. I tested this against V12 version and it works.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dfurman/2015/04/02/collecting-performance-counter-values-from-a-sql-azure-database/